# how to perform alias parsing in python

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to split the alias into the diff array here is the code that I am using

```
def parse_sql_columns_alias(self, sql):
    columns = []
    parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql)
    stmt = parsed[0]
    for token in stmt.tokens:
        if isinstance(token, IdentifierList):
            for identifier in token.get_identifiers():
                columns.append(str(identifier))
        if isinstance(token, Identifier):
            columns.append(str(token))
        if token.ttype is Keyword:  # from
            break
    return columns
```

got below output

```
['empid as eid', 'empname as ename']
```

want output like

```
[eid, ename]
```

Comment: this is the input i have been passing while calling the function 
```obj.parse_sql_columns_alias('select empid as eid, empname as ename from emp ')```

Comment: Have you thought of looking for the keyword `' as '` in the token, and using the latter partition of the token if the keyword is found?

Comment: yes, if we found  ' as ' in the query then i need to store original name and alias name in the diff dictonary.

Comment: There you have it then. Pretty straightforward to implement.